# GoogleMaps API (Android) – Draw PolyLine between the edges of Markers adjusting with Zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Using the GoogleMaps API on Android, I have a series of Markers added to a MapOverlay.

These markers remain the same size on the screen as the user zooms the map.

I have a PolyLine that joins these markers and it currently runs from the center of each marker to the next.

I want to change this so that the PolyLine starts and finishes at the edge of each marker.

My problem is that the Lat/Lng of the edges change as the user zooms.

What is the best way to do this?

I currently add my Markers and Line(s) as follows:

```
markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng)
    .anchor(0.5F, 0.5F).draggable(false).visible(true)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(markerId));
this.googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
options.add(new LatLng(controlPointEnd1.getLatitude(),controlPointEnd1.getLongitude()));
…
this.googleMap.addPolyline(options.width(4).color(Color.MAGENTA).geodesic(false));
```

[Screen shot showing: Ground overlay, a couple of markers and the PolyLine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWmeS.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you share the image that you are using for your markers?

Comment: @antonio thanks - I've added a screen shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Objectives

I can see that you are using icons in form of circle and would like to create a Polyline that joins borders of circles, but not their centres.

Here we have to solve following question:

1. Calculate a radius of circle marker in screen pixels. As the icon is not changing the size it will be a constant value.
2. Calculate offset positions of coordinates on the circle borders and draw polyline between these points

### Solution

The relevant code to calculate circle radius in screen pixels is the following

```
//Let's calculate what is a radius in screen pixels for our icon
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
Drawable m_icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawableForDensity(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_circle,dm.densityDpi,null);
int height = ((BitmapDrawable)m_icon).getBitmap().getHeight();
int width = ((BitmapDrawable)m_icon).getBitmap().getWidth();

iconRadiusPixels = width / 2;
```

I suppose that you have a drawable resource R.drawable.ic_circle for the circle icon. This code can be located in the onCreate() method.

The next is the function that calculates the offset position for points on the border. We will need [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/) that has SphericalUtil class which we can use to calculate heading between points and offsets for circle radius. You have to include the utility library in your gradle as `compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'`. The relevant part of the code is the following

```
private void showCustomPolyline () {
    //Get projection
    Projection proj = mMap.getProjection();
    //Get a point on the screen that corresponds to first marker
    Point p = proj.toScreenLocation(sydney1);
    //Lets create another point that is shifted on number of pixels iqual to icon radius
    //This point is located on circle border
    Point b = new Point(p.x + iconRadiusPixels, p.y);
    //Get the LatLng for a point on the circle border
    LatLng l = proj.fromScreenLocation(b);
    //Calculate the radius of the icon (distance between center and point on the circle border)
    double r = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(sydney1,l);
    //Calculate heading from point 1 to point 2 and from point 2 to point 1
    double heading1 = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(sydney1, sydney2);
    double heading2 = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(sydney2, sydney1);

    //Calculate real position where the polyline starts and ends taking into account radius and heading
    LatLng pos1 = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(sydney1, r, heading1);
    LatLng pos2 = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(sydney2, r, heading2);

    //Create polyline
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
    options.add(pos1);
    options.add(pos2);

    poly = mMap.addPolyline(options.width(4).color(Color.RED).geodesic(false));
}
```

Finally you can listen camera events like GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener or GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener and repaint the polyline when the camera is moving. For simplicity let's repaint polyline when the camera finished movement

```
@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {
    if (this.poly != null) {
        this.poly.remove();
        this.poly = null;
    }
    this.showCustomPolyline();
}
```

### Conclusion

You can download a sample project with complete code from GitHub

https://github.com/xomena-so/so43303695

Just replace my API key with yours in the `app/src/debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml`

[image]

Comment: Thanks that's fantastic. And thanks for the demo project - much appreciated. Do you know if there is a similar SphericalUtil class for iOS?